# Are non-english characters 100% supported in codeigniter urls by default?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, urlencode, codeigniter-url, non-english

I want to be sure if this behavior is 100% supported in CodeIgniter.

What doubts me is that in `config.php` the `permitted_uri_chars` is as followed:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

It says that **only English chars** are allowed. BUT consider the results of following urls:

- `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/controller/method/hell0-there+++`

Result: `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`

- `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/controller/method/hello-سلام`

Result: No problem!!!

The word `سلام` (which is in Persian and means "hello") cannot be accepted by the pattern `'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-'`, but it doesn't error like the previous example!

**Why does this behavior happen?**

**Now the next question: Is there any NEED to add and include Persian characters in the pattern?**

I was thinking of changing the `config.php` to be like this:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

// Add all the persian characters after standard pattern:
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] .= 'آابپتثجچحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیي‌۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-ASCII character should be URLEncoded converting them to `%F3` etc. Which I believe would be allowed based on the `%` and `a-z 0-9`

Comment: +1 Perfect and conclusive answer! I never thought of such a solution (base on converting and relating to `urlencode()`). Thank you very much :) I will also update the tag for SEO.

Comment: Dear friend, you should wait one more minute! That's what I should do, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use it in this way, Change the Config File:

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-|آ-ی';`

In This way it supports all charachters except "Hamze". And if you want to Support "Hamze" you can change it in this way :

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-|آ-یء';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just read your question and it has a simple answer that i have reached! The answer is :

```
$route[urlencode ('ورود-به-حساب-کاربری')] = 'Login';
```

You do not need to manipulate your config file as you told! So you only need to set this line of code into your `route.php` as well.
It works for me.

Comment: This is far better answer, as i want keep other language text visible in url, but want to pass through uri restrictions in $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-'; i donot think any security concern as only words specified in routing will be passed.

Comment: I'm so happy to hear that it was useful for you.