# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters Error when use persian characters in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, url

Hello When I use Persian Characters in my URL in Codeigniter I get this error:

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

How I chan fix This problem?

my URL: [http://localhost:11000/mahd/web/tops/posts/create_result/سلام](http://localhost:11000/mahd/web/tops/posts/create_result/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85)

I open this URL in jquery

```
window.open('<?=base_url();?>tops/posts/create_result/'+SearchValue,'_blank');
```

Comment: you can add the persian alphabet as a regular expression in **application/config/config.php** in `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9 ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی~%.:_\-';`  without spaces

Comment: I use $config['permitted_uri_chars'] ='a-z 0-9ابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی~%.:_\-';    and  
   $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9 ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی~%.:_\-'; But Not worked

Comment: may be try http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Not Work this link php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: This solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28623691/2085899